# Shifted value with NSString * and void*

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, keychain

I want to pass to a method a void* from a NSString get in a NSTextField so I did like this :

(It is to add a new password to the keychain access on OS X)

```
 NSString *password = [passwordTextField stringValue];
UInt32 passwordlength = (UInt32) [password length];


void *mypassword = malloc(passwordlength);
mypassword = &password;

StorePasswordKeychain(mypassword, passwordlength);
```

The problem is that if passwordTextField returns "hello" for example, i get back in the keychain "xhell". the x is random..

I think that it is a basic problem but i can't figure how to solve it ..

Comment: This code is almost certainly wrong: `[passwordTextField stringValue]`.  Unless `passwordTextField` isn't a text field.

Comment: I'd say this code is total nonsense. You first set mypassword to the result of malloc, and then you set it to the address of an NSString* variable. What the hell do you expect to happen?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should not assume how `NSString` object store it internal representation. In your case, first byte probably occupied with string length or other `NSString` internal data. Use following code instead:

```
NSString *password = [passwordTextField stringValue];
void *mypassword = (void *)[password UTF8String];
StorePasswordKeychain(mypassword, strlen(mypassword));
```

If you need different encoding, use `cStringUsingEncoding:` method instead of `UTF8String`.

Answer (score 2):

The Keychain stores a password not as a string but as a collection of bytes and a byte count. Assuming your `StorePasswordKeychain` is a customised (with your app details) version of the example function given in [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/03tasks/tasks.html) then it just a simple wrapper around `SecKeychainAddGenericPassword` which takes just a pointer to the bytes and the byte count.

To convert an `NSString` into bytes you can convert it into a C-style string using the method `UTF8String` and then use the C function `strlen` to count the number of bytes.

```
const char *passwordBytes = [password UTF8String];
StorePasswordKeychain(passwordBytes, strlen(passwordBytes));
```

*Important: the number of bytes may be larger than the number of characters in the Objective-C string as Unicode characters can require more than 1 byte to encode in UTF8 format. So **do not** pass the character count (using the `length` method) or you will have code that appears to work but had a subtle bug.*

HTH